# Javascript Json

Tags: javascript

Olá pessoal preciso montar um objeto deste tipo:

```
{y: "2017-8", a: 0, b: 0, c: 2, d: 0, …}
```

As letras vão até h, mas pode variar de um usuário pra outro, estou montando um grafico linha *Morris.Line*.
O meu servidor me retorna um array:

```
["a: 0", "b: 1", "c: 0", "d: 0"]
```

Se eu colocar isso com toString() obtenho:

```
console.log(x);
a: 0,b: 1,c: 0,d: 0
```

Aparentemente perfeito mas, não resolve meu problema pois se eu colocar dentro do objeto que preciso inicializar pra fazer meu gráfico obtenho:

```
console.log({y: data, x});
{y: "2017-8", x: "a: 0,b: 1,c: 0,d: 0"}
```

Se eu colocar o array direto também não fica como preciso; Obtenho:

```
console.log({y: data, x});
{y: "2017-8", x: Array(4)}
```

Bom galera como faço pra obter aquilo que coloquei lá no começo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
a = ["a: 0", "b: 1", "c: 0", "d: 0"];
obj = {};
obj['y'] = '2017-8';
a.forEach(function(el, i){
    var arr = el.split(': ');
    obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
});
console.log(obj);

{y: "2017-8", a: "0", b: "1", c: "0", d: "0"}
```

Comment: valeu guerreiro!

Comment: Por nada, qual lib você está usando para gerar o gráfico @AbnerPassosMagalhaes ?

Comment: https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html

Answer (score 0):

Pra fins de "code golfing" :D

```
let arrayDoServer = ["a: 0", "b: 1", "c: 0", "d: 0"];
let jsonDeSaida   = JSON.parse('{"' + arrayDoServer.join('","').replace(/: /g, '":"') + '"}');
console.log(jsonDeSaida);
```